# Best way to get data from MS Project to Excel

Tags: ms-project

I have created an excel file that outputs a really nice report for me after taking the input of Task name, resources, start date and finish date. The excel file is quite complicated and isn't something that can be replicated multiple times, however I only need to produce this report once a year. What is the best way for me to get this data from project into the existing excel file. Is it simply copying and pasting or does it require a script? Thank you.

Comment: I ended up learning a little bit of VBA to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the best way to get what I wanted was to use VBA so I wrote a basic script.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a flat file of your MSP DATA with Files > Save as > Save as file > Ok > then choose Excel type file > Save > Next > Next> New mapping and Next > choose task and Next > then add the collums you want and finish > save your mapping

You now have all data in a file that you can use for your dashboard

Comment: This will require a new excel file every time correct? I was hoping there was a way to map to an existing excel file and overwrite existing columns.

Comment: yes you have to export every time, but if your first file refer to the export data, you will not have to do any ajustement, only export from the mapping you save.  If you want to have an excel who get the data from MSP you have to code in VBA, wich is another level of complexity.